# Sending an Async Post WebRequest, I get a (411) Length Required

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I am using the code below to post to a web site but I get a 411 error, (
*`The remote server returned an error: (411) Length Required`)*.

This is the function I am using, I just removed the exception handling. I get a `WebException` been thrown.

```
private static async Task<string> PostAsync(string url, string queryString, Dictionary<string, string> headers)
{
  var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
  webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
  webRequest.Method = "POST";
  if (headers != null)
  {
    foreach (var header in headers)
    {
      webRequest.Headers.Add(header.Key, header.Value);
    }
  }

  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryString))
  {
    queryString = BuildQueryString(query);
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream()))
    {
      writer.Write(queryString);
    }
  }

  //Make the request
  try
  {
    using (
      var webResponse = await Task<WebResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(webRequest.BeginGetResponse, webRequest.EndGetResponse, webRequest).ConfigureAwait(false))
    {
      using (var str = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
      {
        if (str != null)
        {
          using (var sr = new StreamReader(str))
          {
            return sr.ReadToEnd();
          }
        }
        return null;
      }
    }
  }
  catch (WebException wex)
  {
    // handle webexception
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    // handle webexception
  }
}
```

I saw on some site that adding

```
webRequest.ContentLength = 0;
```

Would work, but in some cases I get errors that the length is wrong, (so it must be something other than 0).

So my questions are, how do I set the content length properly?

And, am I sending my `post` requests properly? Is there another way?

Not sure if it matters, but I am using .NET 4.6, (but I can use 4.6.1 if needed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The length is the length of the data you're writing to the request stream. So in this bit, set the `ContentLength`:

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream()))
{
  writer.Write(queryString);
  request.ContentLength = queryString.Length;
}
```

Note that you might have trouble if `queryString` contains unicode characters. The `ContentLength` indicates the number of bytes, but `string.Length` indicates the number of characters. Since some unicode characters take up more than one byte, there can possibly be a mismatch. There are ways to compensate if need be.

As an alternative, you can use [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx) instead. I haven't had to set the ContentLength manually when using it.

Comment: I think there might be more to this, if I make the changes you suggested I now get "`System.Net.ProtocolViolationException: Bytes to be written to the stream exceed the Content-Length bytes size specified.`", do I need to include the headers length in the content length? I will have a look at HttpClient, is that the 'prefered' way?

Comment: There is probably a mismatch of bytes vs. character length then. `HttpClient` is the preferred way now. In behind, it's just a wrapper for `HttpWebRequest`, but it's simpler to use. There's an explanation of that here: http://www.diogonunes.com/blog/webclient-vs-httpclient-vs-httpwebrequest/

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `POST` and you need to use `POST` then you need this where `data` represents some data you are posting be it JSON, XML or whatever:

```
request.ContentLength = data.Length;
```

Having said that, I think you are probably ok with using `GET` instead since you are not sending nothing in the body of the request. But in some cases you have no choice but to use `POST`.

Comment: Thanks, but I seem to have an issue finding what the data length actually is. Given my code, how would you calculate the 'proper' data length?

Comment: Did you try `GET` like I mentioned?

Comment: Yes, I am testing it now, and i am no longer getting error, (I am still testing). But I must admit that I would like to understand why the POST is not working, it does not really make sense.

Comment: If the server side has limited the call to only `GET` then `POST` will not work.

Comment: Of course, but it would give me a different error, (I suspect).